# Type does not conform to protocol Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Started practicing Swift. In `singleViewController` I am trying to make a `UICollectionView`. In storyboard I set the `dataSource` and `delegate`. Here I am getting the error:

> 'UICollectionView' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'

```
import UIKit

class galeriacontroler: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!

    let fotosgaleria = [UIImage(named: "arbol3"), UIImage(named:"arbol4")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.fotosgaleria.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellImagen", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! cellcontroler

        cell.imagenView2?.image = self.fotosgaleria[indexPath.row]
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showImage", sender: self )
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showImage"
        {
            let indexPaths = self.collectionview!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
            let indexPath = indexPaths![0] as NSIndexPath

            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! newviewcontroler

            vc.image = self.fotosgaleria[indexPath.row]!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UICollectionViewDataSource` has two required methods - 
`collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` and `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)`, of which you have implemented only one.

You need to add an implementation for `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)` to fix this problem:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell {
    var  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionCell
    ... // Do more configuration here
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you import **UICollectionViewDataSource** you must implement **cellForItemAtIndexPath**  method

Add the following method to your code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imagesCellIdentifier", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! cellcontroler
cell.secondImageView?.image = self.photosGalleryArray[indexPath.row]

return cell
}
```

**willDisplayCell** is not necessary to implement after this.